# Fail to call the each function in DolphinDB due to the error Cannot recognize the token a

Tags: foreach, each, dolphindb

The script below triggers the error `Cannot recognize the token a`. How to modify this script?

```
a = `a`b`c
each(i -> each(add{i,}, a), 1..10)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your script, the function `each(add{i,}, a)` references the external variable *a*, which is not an input parameter. Since a function cannot reference external variables, an error is triggered. You can modify the script as follows:

```
a = `a`b`c
def f(i, a):each(add{i,}, a)
each(f{,a}, 1..10)
```